# how to select first row in table

Tags: sql, hive

i am trying to select first occurrence of the "Quality" column per each Type (A, B, C, ...etc)

```
infotable
--------
time   Type   quality
1:00   A      1
1:05   A      1
1:10   A      2
1:13   A      2
1:17   A      3
1:20   B      3
1:22   B      2
1:25   B      2
1:30   B      1

and i want the final result to be like this:
--------------------------
time   Type   quality
1:00   A      1
1:10   A      2
1:17   A      3
1:20   B      3
1:22   B      2
1:30   B      1
```

i tried to do it through multiple CTE but failed to get the correct output

```
with 
  cte_type
as (
  select *,
  row_number() over (partition by type order by time asc ) as rn_type
  from infotable
  ),
  cte_quality
  as (
  select *,
  row_number() over (partition by quality order by time asc ) as rn_quality
  from cte_type
  )
select * from cte_quality
where rn_quality = 1;
```

Any thoughts on how i could get the required result would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a single cte/row_number:

```
with 
  cte
as (
  select *,
     row_number()
     over (partition by type, quality 
           order by time asc ) as rn
  from infotable
  )
select * from cte
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: row_number() only works with certain DBMSs. Op has not stated the DBMS in use.

Comment: @BenHamilton: well, the query shown by MMousa used CTEs and he stated *but failed to get the correct output*

Comment: @BenHamilton: additionally he tagged `hive` which is a SQL-implementation :-)

Comment: many thanks @dnoeth i would go for your answer, as i have many columns in the table and i want to select all data in the first row.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be something like

```
SELECT type, quality, min(time)
FROM infotable
GROUP BY type,quality
```

Comment: The OP's `select *` might indicate additional columns to be returned, otherwise this is the best answer

Comment: If op wants only these 3 columns as he gave in example, this is the simplest answer. But if he needs more column then he need outer query on top of it. +1

Answer (score 0):

no need for cte

```
Select Time, Type, Quality
From infotable it
Where time =
   (Select Min(time)
    From infotable
    Where type = it.Type
       and Quality = it.Quality)
```

This will also show you if there is more than one row for a type & Quality at the same time.